# How to apply one rule to multiple selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to apply a format for all headers.

So, I added

```
 .myformat h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6  {  margin-bottom : 1em; ... }
```

Written like that, it doesn't consider the first `hx`. The rules aren't applied to h1.

When I write it like

```
 .myformat h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h1  {  margin-bottom : 1em; ... }
```

everything is fine. The rules are applied to h1, h2, ... and h6.

It's suspicious... I guess that I have a problem somewhere else but I'm unable to see it.

Is it the correct way to apply a rule to multiple selectors ?

I have the same behavior on IE9 and Chrome20 on window. Also replicated on Firefox12 on Fedora15

---

EDIT

I want to be able to do something like

```
<h1 class="myformat">This text will be red and 
                     or all hx where I apply "myformat"
</h1>
<p class="myformat">This text will be yellow only
                    when myformat is applied on a paragraph
</p>
```

I created `.myformat h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6  {  margin-bottom : 1em; ... }` believing this "myformat" will only be applied on headers.

I wasto be creating `.myformat p {  margin-bottom : 3em; ... }`
but I blocked on `<h1 class="myformat">text</h1>`

Comment: Obviously the second example works because you added `h1`. Not sure what you find suspicious. The selector `.myformat h1` selects only an `h1` that's a child of `.myformat`... Does that clear anything up for you? What are you expecting `.myformat` to do and why are you using it?

Comment: @WesleyMurch I was expecting to rules to be applied to all hx child or not. I think I completely misundersood this css behavior. I have some reading to do I guess.

Comment: I'll ask again hoping to clarify your question: Why are you using `.myformat h1` instead of just `h1`?

Answer (score 6):

Try it like this .myformat h1, .myformat h2, .myformat h3, etc etc.

This is assuming that the h1's h2's h3's are all in a div called .myformat.

You can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/fYgdA/5/

Answer (score 4):

You're using the correct syntax. The problem you're having likely has to do with the selector `.myformat h1`. Check your html code, that selector will only find an `h1` which is within an element with the class `myformat`. For example:

```
<div class='myformat'>
   <h1>Header One</h1>
</div>
```

If `myformat` is on the `h1` then you'll want to use the selector `h1.myformat`. So that selector will work if your html is like:

```
<h1 class='myformat'>Header One</h1>
```

Comment: @LucM: If the element with the class `myformat` is within the `h1` element, then you would use `h1 .myformat` to target that inner element. There is no way (in current CSS) to target a `h1` that contains an element with the class `myformat`.

Answer (score 2):

It would be appropriate to have one rule `.myformat{margin-bottom:1em;}` if your markup resembles the sample below. This will work because of selector specificity and will apply to any element that has `myformat` class.

```
<h1 class="myformat">Header</h1>
<h2 class="myformat">Subheader</h2>
...
```

Given that you want to separately style *headers* and *paragraphs* with this same `myformat` class, you have two options. You could either have verbose (overqualified) selectors like

```
h1.myformat, h2.myformat, h3.myformat {/*some style*/}
p.myformat {/*some other style*/}
```

or you could opt-in for separate class names which would be preferable imo

```
.myformat-title {/*some styles to apply to headers*/}
.myformat-content {/*some styles to apply to paragraphs*/}
```

When you say *`.myformat p...` but I blocked on `<h1 class="myformat">text</h1>`*, what exactly do you mean? If the end result is different from what you've expected, maybe you're experiencing [margin collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)?

Comment: I blocked in the sens that I'm into a dead-end. I didn't know how to solve my problem. I need to improve my english :-)